# Check if A is a subclass of B?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am currently using Unreal Engine 4 and it seems that I can't avoid some casts.

```
AController* c = this->GetController();
APlayerController* p = (APlayerController*)c;
```

Is there a way that I can check if `c` is a `PlayerController` before I do the cast?

Comment: The way casts tend to work is "try it, did it work?". As Angews answer states, a `dynamic_cast` would be your best bet, followed by a check for a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like a lot of game engines, Unreal Engine is compiled without RTTI for performance reasons, so `dynamic_cast` will not work.

Unreal Engine provides its own alternative, simply called `Cast`. I can't find any documentation for it right now, but [this question](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/1756/non-null-typecasting-validations.html) describes its use nicely.

```
AController* c = this->GetController();
APlayerController* p = Cast<APlayerController>(c);
if (p) {
    ...
}
```

`AController` also has a convenience method [`CastToPlayerController`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AController/CastToPlayerController/index.html) which will do the same thing:

```
AController* c = this->GetController();
APlayerController* p = c->CastToPlayerController();
if (p) {
    ...
}
```

If you are sure that `c` is always going to be an `APlayerController` then `CastChecked` is more efficient:

```
AController* c = this->GetController();
APlayerController* p = CastChecked<APlayerController>(c);
...
```

In debug builds, this will use `Cast` and throw an assert if it would return null; in release builds, it resolves to a fast `static_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I have feeling that you dont need kind of checks for your player controllers, use `IsA` function, you dont need to make extra casts.

```
AController* c = GetController();
if (c->IsA(APlayerController::StaticClass()))
{
    //bla bla
}
```

As a personal suggesstion check your code design

Answer (score 0):

To add to this question (since its first result on google) if you are using Blueprints you have a pure node called "Class is Child Of" if it would be better in your situation than using a cast.